I want to use the condition union if exists with a table referred with {{this}} in snowflake SQL
In dbt, I want to append table if it exists. Basically, I am building an incremental model where I find out lagged values from previous day, for the first run, I want to union today's data along with {{this}}, I know that for the first day {{this}} has no value, so I am trying to skip it in the union.
I am using the below query but it is returning an error:
{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        unique_key='date_run',
        full_refresh=true
    )
}}

with subs_count as 
(
    select 
        current_date() as date_run,
        count(distinct email_address) as distinct_email,
        subscriber
    from {{ source('fan_table_sandbox', 'international_fan_data') }}
    group by date_run,subscriber
),
aggregated_data as 
(
    select
        *
    from subs_count

    union all

    if (exists((select *
                from {{this}} if exists {{this}}
    order by date_run desc limit 1))
),
lag_values as 
(
    select  
        *,
        lag(distinct_email) over (partition by subscriber order by  date_run asc) as previous_day_count
    from aggregated_data
)
select * from lag_values

How can this be resolved?

Use is_incremental. https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/incremental-models#understand-the-is_incremental-macro

I believe you need to use is_incremental() condition.
There are several additional things:

Non-exists column nba_subscriber
You take the latest date_run in aggregated_data, but then do partition by  subscriber. This will lead that you have only one subscriber left from the previous date. You might want to use rank() instead.
On dbt run --full-refresh you will have all historical data deleted. Make sure that is expected. Otherwise change full_refresh config to false or much better approach would be to add created_date field to your international_fan_data table during Extract and Load steps. Then you don't need incremental at all.

{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        unique_key='date_run',
        full_refresh=true
    )
}}

with subs_count as 
(
    select 
        current_date() as date_run,
        count(distinct email_address) as distinct_email,
        subscriber
    from {{ source('fan_table_sandbox', 'international_fan_data') }}
    group by date_run,subscriber
),

aggregated_data as 
(
    select
        *
    from subs_count

    {% if is_incremental() %}

    union all

    select * from {{ this }}
    qualify rank() over(order by date_run desc) = 1

    {% endif %}
),

lag_values as 
(
    select  
        *,
        lag(distinct_email) over (partition by subscriber order by  date_run asc) as previous_day_count
    from aggregated_data
)

select * from lag_values


this worked, thanks a ton!
